# Crossover hover effect - second background isn't responsive

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, hover, lightbox

I'm using a crossover fade with 2 backgrounds, the second background isn't responsive.

HTML:

```
<div class="bord2 crossfd2">
<img src="original image">
</img>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bord2 {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.crossfd2 {
        background: url("transition-image");
        display: inline-block;
        font:size: 0;
  **** the extra code goes here ****
}

.crossfd2 img{
                 -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
                 -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
                 -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
                 transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.crossfd2 img:hover {
                    opacity: 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Adam

---

To fix this issue, add the following CSS:

For background image:

```
.class_with_img {
    background-image:url('img_name.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center;
}
```

Comment: you want 0.5 seconds instead of 1s ... and you think that will be a "slow down"?

Comment: if that's the whole of the css, then it's not the css that is causing your problem

Comment: I meant faster - thanks.

Any idea what the problem is, and how I can fix it? The background image isn't responsive, which sounds like a CSS issue to me.

background: url("transition-image");

is what isn't responding correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a image to be responsive in CSS

```
img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

For background image:

```
.class_with_img {
    background-image:url('img_name.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center;
}
```